# Is `HTML Format` the correct format to put tabular data into the clipboard with SetClipboardData if it will be used for emails?

Tags: c++, excel, winapi, clipboard

We have an in house data table control. We want to support copying the data into the clipboard so that the user can easily paste it into Excel or an email.

I'm considering using the "HTML Format" for the clipboard type, and putting a document that just has a table containing the data into the fragment, using the code referenced in this Microsoft page:

[Add html code to clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/add-html-code-clipboard#:%7E:text=HTML%20has%20its%20own%20clipboard,a%20fragment%20within%20that%20context)

Is `HTML Format` the correct format to use?

Comment: Excel supports a number of formats. Use whichever format you want. But "XML Spreadsheet" or "Biff8" will likely be a better choice then "HTML Format".

Comment: You should put as many formats as you feasibly can on the clipboard. Let the receiving app decide which format it wants to extract from the clipboard.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Is there any documentation on the formats? Its driving me crazy. I tried HTML format and text, but its not clear what is best.

Comment: Documentation on the various formats is scattered, you will have to search around for it.